# windows.postMessage security model of chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Let's call my extension `myextn` and lets say there is another extension `anotherextn`. Both these extensions inject content_scripts when I visit mywebsite.com.

`myextn` content_script does this:

```
   window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
         .....
   });
```

If either  webpage or `anotherextn`'s conent_script does window.postMessage() `myextn`'s content_script gets a message notification. Is there anyway I can differentiate where this message event is coming from? I don't want to trust event.data to make that decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot differentiate between a message from a content script or a web page.

There are also countless ways for a content script to run code in the context of a web page, so you cannot see the difference between a message from a web page, or one from a content script.